# SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server

If I make an SQL server database,

1) Do I need to install SQL server on client's machine too to use it in vb.net or we can use it just without it, as Access database can be used in vb.net.

2) I created a database with one table.  In BindingSource's Datasource section, when I make new connectin with this database, what datasource should be selected
Microsoft SQL Server or Microsoft SQL server database file?

I tried the second one, chose the file but when tested connection, it failed.

Please advise.
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use SQL Lite as an in-memory database without having to install on the client's machine.  Just ship it with your code.
2. I'd see what was required for SQL Lite if you follow the first recommendation.

Comment: Yes please check if for me.  I can use SQL Lite.  Does it mean SQL Databases donot work if SQL server or Lite is not installed?

Comment: You have to have a database of some kind on the client.  You can run both SQL Server and SQL Lite at the same time.  A database listener is just like any other - they simply have to use different ports.

Answer (score 2):

**You will have to have the Sql Server installed**, this is not like MS Access.

Also, have a look at [SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)  for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The client machine will need the SQL server drivers. The machine on which the database is hosted will need the database server installed. You could attach directly to the mdf file on the client if you installed sql erver express on the client.